# Is there a prefered order to MongoDB bindIP addresses?

Tags: mongodb, vagrant-provision

Is there a preferred order of multiple IPs listed in MongoDB's config file (net.bindIP)? Is it better to have the loopback IP listed first?  If so, why?

I am running a replica set (primary-secondary-secondary) configuration.  All 3 machines have the mongodb application set to one of 3 private IP addresses (192.168.x.x) and then the loopback IP (127.0.0.1) address listed after that. All three of my boxes are listening on port 27017 with respect to their own private IP.

Closest to my answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371081/what-does-the-bindip-configuration-option-in-mongodb-do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order does not affect anything.

Comment: thank you.  Verified your answer by playing around with the IP order during a bored weekend.  Each iteration, I was able to communicate with the server.